# .getJson call not working with objects that use inheritence

Tags: c#, jquery, json, inheritance, serialization

first post... Normally I'm able to search and find answers to my problems, but this time I am not able to. I have an object that uses a bunch of other objects:

```
[DataContract]
public class CoolStuff
{
    [DataMember]
    public Field[] CoolField { get; set; }

    public CoolStuff()
    {
        CoolField = SetCoolField();
    }

    private Field[] SetCoolField()
    {
        return new Field[]
        {
            new Field("Project Information", "ProjectInformation"),
            new Field("Resource Information", "ResourceInformation"),
        }
     }
}

[DataContract]
public class Field
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Prompt { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; }

    public Field(string prompt, string value = "n/a", bool isLocked = false)
    {
        Prompt = prompt;
        Value = value;
        IsLocked = isLocked;
    }
}
```

I call my constructors from a service, and this works fine and dandy when I try to serialize it with $.getJSON(/Service.svc/coolstuff/' + id, loadCoolStuff);

The problem is, when I make my Field class inherit from another class, that .getJson call fails without really giving me a reason why.

```
[DataContract]
public class CoolStuff
{
    [DataMember]
    public FieldBase[] CoolField { get; set; }

    public CoolStuff()
    {
        CoolField = SetCoolField();
    }

    private FieldBase[] SetCoolField()
    {
        return new FieldBase[]
        {
            new Field("Project Information", "ProjectInformation"),
            new Field("Resource Information", "ResourceInformation"),
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class FieldBase
{

}

[DataContract]
public class Field : FieldBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Prompt { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; }

    public Field(string prompt, string value = "n/a", bool isLocked = false)
    {
        Prompt = prompt;
        Value = value;
        IsLocked = isLocked;
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain why with ^ this code, my call to .getJSON fails? I'm really stuck here. Thanks so much!

Comment: What json-serializer are you using? ASP.NET MVC's default? ASP.NET WebApi default? Newtonsoft?

Comment: sorry, I'm using the asp.net default one, I think. I know absolutely NOTHING about serializing, I'm inheriting this project from someone else.

Comment: You should take a look at the data that's being transmitted. Try navigating your browser to the `/Service.svc/coolstuff/' + id` address, and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that and I get the error: failed to load resource, no data received Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data. But if I take out the inheritance it works just fine.

Comment: You've got a few missing closing braces (}) in your code. Other than that, the `SetCoolField` method never actually accomplishes anything in either example. It returns an array, but that array is never assigned to a variable. `CoolField` is never assigned. By changing the call to `CoolField = SetCoolField()`, both examples work fine for me in ASP.NET Web API using the default (Newtonsoft) JSON serializer. This isn't actually the issue you describe, since it works without inheritance, but not with it. Maybe you need to refine your provided samples?

Comment: My bad, this code was just thrown together to show my issue. The setcoolfield method should be called like "Coolfield = setcoolfield();" But either way, my call to .getJSON in my javascript still fails without giving me a real error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, reading between the lines I've deduced you're using WCF for this web service. The use of `DataContract` attributes and url ending in .svc make that clear enough. That's relevant, because this issue seems particular to the way WCF serializes. As mentioned in my above comments, the same class structure has *no* problems in ASP.NET Web API using the default Newtonsoft JSON serializer.

What you need here is the `KnownType` attribute to properly define derived types for serialization.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms751512.aspx) offers some straight-forward examples. [This one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms730167.aspx) has a bit more detail on the concepts.

For the example you've provided, you'd need to decorate the FieldBase definition like this:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Field))]
public class FieldBase
{
}
```

Note that this will add an extra field to your JSON, like `"__type":"Field:#MyTestWebProject"`. You could just ignore that, or go hunting for ways to get rid of it if it bothers you. I wouldn't guarantee it's possible though.